# Using SUBSTR to get two halves of a string

Tags: php, substr

I'm hoping someone out there can see what I'm missing in using PHP's "substr" to get two halves of a 40 character string:

What I have is variable $dk that's 40 chars long.  I've verified the variable's there with an echo statement and it's returning the right value. I've verified the "gkgk" = 1 or 2 as well.  But I'm getting nothing as a result.  Why?

```
$dk = "1234567891123456789212345678931234567894";
echo "<br><br>DK = ".$dk."<br><br>";
if ($a == 1) {
echo "A = 1<br><br>";
$gk = substr($dk, 0, 20); //I'm expecting the first 20 chars...12345678911234567892
} else {
echo "A = 2<br><br>";
$gk = substr($dk, 20, 20); //expecting the last 20 chars...12345678931234567894
}
echo "GK = ".$gk;
```

I tried putting the variable in quotes, just in case it was a syntax issue.  All I get is

DK =1234567891123456789212345678931234567894

A = 1

GK =

No clue what's going wrong.  I hope I've given enough explanation and my code so people can understand!  Thank you for any help.

Comment: Where is the value of "A" being set?

Comment: try adding (string) before the $dk declarations like this: `$gk = substr((string)$dk, 0, 20);`

Comment: @Len_D , $a is being set manually.  Since it's echoing the "A = 1" part I know that it's reaching into that part of the "if" statement...

Comment: works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/09v0Ly

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? It could be trying to scope the variable.  Try adding  `$gk = "DefaultValue";` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: @iamde_coder -- that didn't seem to work.  Is "substr" not realizing this is a string and processing it as a number?

Comment: @user1149499 that was my theory but if it didn't work then it must be something else, your code works on my end perfectly fine. can you possibly add some more of your code to give us some more info to go off of?

Comment: `$gk = str_split($dk, 20)[$a-1]`.... though that does require a modern version of PHP

Comment: This works as expected on my server.

    <?php
    $a = '1';
    $dk = "1234567891123456789212345678931234567894";
    echo "<br><br>DK = ".$dk."<br><br>";
    if ($a == 1) {
    echo "A = 1<br><br>";
    $gk = substr($dk, 0, 20); //I'm expecting the first 20 chars...12345678911234567892
    } else {
    echo "A = 2<br><br>";
    $gk = substr($dk, 20, 20); //expecting the last 20 chars...12345678931234567894
    }
    echo "GK = ".$gk;
    ?>

Comment: Okay, knowing that this code is correct is enough for me.  I'm using 5.4 so it's not that it's an old version of PHP.  It must be something (probably dumb) that I'm doing elsewhere that's factoring in.  Thank you for the suggestions/confirmations...at least I know it's not this part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Code is correct but if you are checking $a is one or two, first of all u must add value to $a variable.

above of this ---> if ($a == 1) { <-------- add this $a=1;
or 
above of this ---> if ($a == 1) { <-------- add this $a=2;

Comment: I know that it's seeing $a as 1 or $a as 2 because it's giving me the right echo line...so it's not that...but thanks for the suggestion.